# XPath test to see if all the children's attributes have a certain value

Tags: xpath

This is a simple XML file in which I want to do an XPath test:

```
<Prop>
    <Attx>
        <Atty tip="ddd"></Atty>
        <Atty tip="ddd"></Atty>
        <Atty tip="ddd"></Atty>
    </Attx>   
</Prop>
```

I would like to see if **all** `tip` attributes of all the `Atty` elements equal `ddd`.

I implemented this with the following XPath query:

```
count(/Prop/Attx/Atty[@tip='ddd'])=count(/Prop/Attx/Atty)
```

Is there a simpler query which can achieve the same test?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This XPath expression:

```
/Prop/Attx/Atty/@tip != 'ddd'
```

**Meaning**: there is at least one `@tip` attribute not equal to `'ddd'`

Comment: Beat me to it :) I'd /Prop/Attx/Atty[not(@tip = "ddd")].

Comment: i'm a stupid man! So easy, so logic! Sorry for the truly question :-(

Answer (score 4):

This expression will only return true if all Atty elements have an attribute *tip* with value "ddd":

```
not(//Atty[not(@tip = 'ddd')])
```

Alternatively, the following expression will also return true if there are Atty elements with no *tip* attribute. It only returns false if there's an Atty element with a *tip* attribute that has a value other than "ddd":

```
not(//Atty[@tip and not(@tip = 'ddd')])
```

The path can of course be made more specific rather than the "**//**" anywhere selector. Should work in XPath 1.0 and 2.0.